# Vim on windows works weirdly when using it as git editor

Tags: windows, git, vim

When I'm using git and running any command which intends to open an editor (like `git commit` or `git rebase -i`) it opens up vim as expected in powershell but it behaves very strangely.
If i press `<Ctrl + Right arrow>` it erases a lot of content in the file and turns insert mode on but it should advance the cursor to the end of the next word keeping the current mode
If i open `COMMIT_EDITMSG` in another terminal with powershell and proceed with E (Forcing it not to use swap) it works just fine. I tried different terminal emulators like cmd and powershell terminal but it works the same (weird) way in all of them

Comment: Does it work in Git Bash?  It's possible `TERM` is not set correctly, resulting in a weird terminal emulation being used.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using neovim instead of vim

Answer (score 0):

Note that it also act strangely when *leaving* vim, displaying the commit message poorly:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/929932/110089418-6354cb80-7d96-11eb-8544-22c30c4a3a35.png]

This is followed by [`microsoft/terminal` issue 9359](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/9359), and mentioned in the latest [Git For Windows release 2.34](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.34.0.windows.1): check if Git 2.34 would behave better with vim in your case.